# ESP32 - unable to connect to Google Coud VM running Node-Red httpin node with post/get request

Tags: web, arduino, esp32

I have a Google Cloud Debian VM with Node Red installed.
I created a flow that is refered as json on the httpin node. When I http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1880/json from chrome, Node Red at the VM responds with a test json string I typed there.

My intention is to post a json from ESP32 and get a response from Node Red.
But I am just unable to even connect with the above URL from ESP32.

At the top of my sketch I have:

```
String URLWebServer          = "http://222.222.111.128";
int    PortWebServer         = 1880;
String uploadScript          = "/json";
```

Later in the sketch I have the web connection as below:

```
void postWebServer(){
  Serial.print("Connect to " + URLWebServer);
  if (webClient.connect(URLWebServer.c_str(), PortWebServer)){
    Serial.println(" -> OK");
...
...
...
  }else{
    Serial.println(" -> Fail");
  }
```

And no matter what I do I always get "-> Fail").

Assistance welcome.

---

The sketch is divided in several tabs with specific functions.
This is the same sketch I use to connect with another online service and it used to work. Now I am developing my own service using nodered.
When this function is called WiFi is already connected.
Complete code of the function that does the web post:

```
void postWebServer(){
  Serial.print("Connect to " + URLWebServer); 
  if (webClient.connect(URLWebServer.c_str(), PortWebServer)){
    Serial.println(" -> OK");
    String startBoundary = "--";
    String postTail = startBoundary + boundary + "--" + newLine;

    String strBody;  // = newLine;
    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += ftpFileName + newLine;
    
    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"devid\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += devid + newLine;

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"latitude\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += "123" + newLine;    

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"longitude\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += "345" + newLine;    

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"camera_id\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += camera_id + newLine;

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"maxSpeed\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += "40" + newLine;

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"radarSpeed\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += "65" + newLine;    

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"plate\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += plate + newLine;

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += type + newLine;

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"make\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += make + newLine;

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"model\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += model + newLine;        

    strBody += startBoundary + boundary + newLine;
    strBody += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"color\"" + newLine + newLine;
    strBody += color + newLine;
    strBody += postTail;  
    
    Serial.println("Connection to " + URLWebServer + " - OK"); 
    String header = "POST " + uploadScript + " HTTP/1.1" + newLine;    
    header += "Host: " + URLWebServer + newLine;      
    header += "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary + newLine;    
    header += "Content-Length: " + String(strBody.length()) + newLine;
    header += newLine;

    webClient.print(header);
    pDBGln(header);                
    webClient.print(strBody);  
    pDBGln(strBody + newLine);
        
    Serial.println("Data sent to " + URLWebServer + "...");

  }else{
    Serial.println(" -> Fail");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paulo Borges - there's not nearly enough information in the sketch you provided to help you. For instance, it really matters what `webClient` is but you haven't provided that portion of the code. Please post a [complete, minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem. Cut out everything that doesn't matter, make sure the code builds and has the problem and share that. As it stands it's like you're asking "Why do I have a headache"... I don't know, why do you?

Comment: Added the whole function of interest. Hope it clarifies enough. As I said, this is a sketch that was already working on another online service but I decided to develop my own using NodeRed. The problem takes place right on the top on the webclient connection. This server is http only (no https).

Comment: The problem is right here: "if (webClient.connect(URLWebServer.c_str(), PortWebServer)){". the complete path to the service is "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1880/jpg". If I type "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:1880" I get the NodeRed console. I am trying to move this httpin node to operate on port 8080 and will see if it accepts connection but I am still struggling to open this port at the VM firewall setup.

Comment: Again, I'd point out you haven't included all the code of interest. We have to assume that `webClient` is a WiFiClient object. Providing a complete, minimal program would avoid that. But @hardlib's answer below is almost certainly correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess since you haven't really provided enough context to your ESP32 code.

But it looks like `webClient` is actually an ethernet/wifi client since you are building the HTTP request by hand in the function you have provided.

You need to take the `http://` off the start of the `URLWebServer` it should be a hostname/ip address not a URL, since you are passing the port as a separate argument.

You will need to include the `http://` in the HTTP Host header  (along with the port number)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host

Comment: Great! solved the problem, thanks. Sorry for not providing the whole thing, it is really big. Good that you could figure out what was wrong. Thanks again.